# angularJS $stateParams in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I try to fetch JSON data on the page post/:postId within the following **factory** in my **service**:

```
angular.module('sampleapp.services', [])
    .factory('DetailService', function($http) {
        return {
            getDetail: function(callback) {
                $http.get('https://example.com/posts/' + $stateParams.postId + '.json').success(callback);
            }
        };
    });
```

Unfortunately, $stateParams is undefined. What am I doing wrong? If I hardcode the URL, it works.

My **routing**:

```
.state('detail', {
    url: '/post/:postId',
    templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
    controller: 'DetailCtrl'
})
```

and my **controller**:

```
.controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope, DetailService) {
    DetailService.getDetail(function(data) {
        $scope.post = data;
    });
});
```

My question is: How can i access the URL-paramters within my factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you inject the $http service, you must also inject the $stateParams service:

```
.factory('DetailService', function($http, $stateParams) {
```