# How do I obtain $stateParams in Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-ui-router

Here is my `state` definition:

```
.state('sub-topic',{
    url:"/topics/:topicId",
    templateUrl: "templates/sub-topics.html",
    controller: "SubTopicsController"
})
```

Here is my `service`

```
myApp.service('subTopicsService',function($http, $stateParams){

    this.getSubTopics = function(){
        $http.get('topics/' + $stateParams.topicId + '.json').success(function(data, status, header, config) {
             return data;
        });
    }
})
```

A part of my `controller`, that has `'subTopicService'` injected

```
$scope.topicList = subTopicsService.getSubTopics();
```

The problem is, the `$stateParams` is `undefined` in the service.
Specifically I get this error message: `Cannot access property :topicId of undefined.`
How do I use `$stateParams` in my service?

Comment: see the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799161/angularjs-stateparams-in-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario should work. There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ysedZBASaxtzXtwxKq9?p=preview). Changes I made:

I just restructred the service definition:

```
myApp.service('subTopicsService', function($http, $stateParams) {

  var getSubTopics = function() {
    $http.get('topics/' + $stateParams.topicId + '.json ')
      .success(function(data, status, header, config) {
        return data;
      });
  };
  // to prove, that this service can work with $stateParams
  var getStateParams = function() {
    return $stateParams;
  };

  return {
    getSubTopics: getSubTopics,
    getStateParams: getStateParams,
  };
});
```

Here we get the service injected into controller:

```
myApp.controller('SubTopicsController', function($scope, $state, subTopicsService) {

  $scope.stateParams = subTopicsService.getStateParams();
});
```

And here is our view, consuming that all:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('sub-topic', {
      url: "/topics/:topicId",
      //templateUrl: "templates/sub-topics.html",
      template: '<div><pre>{{stateParams}}</pre></div>',
      controller: "SubTopicsController",
    });
```

See the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ysedZBASaxtzXtwxKq9?p=preview) for more detauls

Comment: Thanks a lot. And also have a look at this http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-do-i-obtain-stateparams-in-angular-sevice/5357/2

What do you think?

Comment: As I've shown in the plunker, you definitely do not have to pass it into controller. the $stateParams are in fact defined as a `value`. That means, that we can ask angular $injector to inject that even in a service - for sure ;)

Comment: Wanted to say, that in comparison with the answer you've send in the comment above - we do not have to pass it from controller (a cited suggestion: `etSubTopics = function(paramsFromCtrl)`). We can go the way you wanted, i.e. let the angular inject the $stateParams directly into our service `service('subTopicsService', function($http, $stateParams)` ... so, what you want, is what you get ;)